# Are there any $n$ for which $ n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any positive $n$ for which $ n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square?

I tried to simplify

\begin{align*}
n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1 &= n^2(n^2+1)+n(n^2+1)+1\\
 &= (n^2+n)(n^2+1)+1 \\
  &= n(n+1)(n^2+1)+1
\end{align*}
Then I assumed that the above expression is a square; then

$$ n(n+1)(n^2+1)+1 = k^2$$

$$ 
\begin{align*}
n(n+1)(n^2+1) &= (k^2-1) \\
   &= (k+1)(k-1)
\end{align*}
$$

Then trying to reason with prime factors, but cannot find a concrete proof yet.

Comment: $n=0$ and $n=-1$ both work.

Comment: Ribenboim's book on Catalan's conjecture has a detailed analysis of the Diophantine equation 
$v^2=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n−1}$. 
The only non-trivial solutions are $n=5,x=3$ and $n=4,x=7$.
By non-trivial, I mean $|x|>1$.

Comment: Wow! that was very useful to know

Comment: $n^4 + 4 n^3 + 6 n^2 + 4 n + 1$ works better.

Comment: which is $(n+1)^4 = \left(\left(n+1\right)^2\right)^2$

Comment: Alright, if you insist.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Is that book available for a reasonable price anywhere? If not, do you know if it's [legally] available on line? A Google search seems to indicate not.

Comment: @rogerl Not that I know of. We have a copy in our university library, which is how I got ahold of it.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you want positive integers $n$,

I believe we can show that

$$(2n^2 + n)^2 \lt 4(n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1) \lt (2n^2 + n + 1)^2$$

for $n \gt 3$.

Note: A similar inequality can be given for negative $n$.

Comment: Yes $n$ is positive integer.

Comment: Since you need $n^2>2n+3$, you must have $n>3$.  Note in particular, when $n=3$, $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1=121=11^2$.

Comment: Yes I got it Aryabhata. That was a fantastic hint.

Comment: I did get for n=3, but proving that it cannot have any other $n$ is where I can use Aryabhata's hint.

Comment: @EricNaslund: Thanks! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is my answer!

H. Bensom, Germany

Comment: Your answer is very confusingly written and the special case you found ($n=3$) is already included in Byron Schmuland's comment.