# When is $\sum_{n=0}^{4}{x^n},~\text{where}~x\in \mathbb{N}>0$ square?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

When is $\sum_{n=0}^{4}{x^n}$  ($x$ a natural number greater $0$) square ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look for the Diophantine equation $(x^n-1)/(x-1)=y^2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I did, yet I didn't see how it helps me. My first idea was that their gcd is one, but...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is given in Ribenboim's book on [Catalan's conjecture](http://books.google.at/books/about/Catalan_s_conjecture.html?id=SOzuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), where all Diophantine equations $$y^2=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^k$$ are studied.
For $k=3$, only $x=1$ and $x=7$ are possible. For $k=4$, well, find out! (solution at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116064/are-there-any-n-for-which-n4n3n2n1-is-a-perfect-square)).