# Find sum of all $n$ such that $4n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n+1$ be perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find sum of all $n$ such that $4n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n+1$ be perfect square.

Here I tried.

We know that $n=0$ is trivial.
Note that $4n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n+1=(2n^2-n+1)(2n^2+2n+1)$. Now, $(2n^2+2n+1)\equiv  1 \pmod 4, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since the all perfect square numbers, say $k^2$, $k^2\equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$, then we must have $2n^2-n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$. I found some $n$ that satisfied is: $n=\lbrace -1,3 \rbrace$. But, I don't know to ensure that only them that satisfied.
Can anyone explain it? Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116064/are-there-any-n-for-which-n4n3n2n1-is-a-perfect-square

Comment: sorry? what should i do? different problem

Comment: The solutions seem to be $n=-1,0,3$.

Comment: how to fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $$\left(2n^2+\frac{1}{2}n\right)^2<4n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n+1\leq\left(2n^2+\frac{1}{2}n+1\right)^2.$$ Also, $$\left(2n^2+\frac{1}{2}(n-1)\right)^2<4n^4+2n^3+2n^2+n+1\leq\left(2n^2+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)\right)^2,$$ where the right inequality is true for $(n+1)(n-3)\geq0.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: but, $n=0$ satisfied i.e. 1 is perfect square.

Comment: @arnold We obtain it for even  $n$ from the right inequality of the first case.

Comment: oh, see. from the first ineq, that is $\frac{9}{4}n \geq 0$ i.e. $n \geq 0$ right?

Comment: so, the solutions is $n \leq -1$ and $n \geq 3$?

Comment: @arnold For odd $n\geq3$ or $n\leq-1$ we have $4n^2+2n^3+2n^2+n+1=\left(2n^2+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)\right)^2.$ For even $n$ we got $4n^2+2n^3+2n^2+n+1=\left(2n^2+\frac{1}{2}n+1\right)^2$

Comment: Seems strange, because if we divide all terms by coefficient of $n^4$ the coefficient of $n^3$ is $2/5$ which is the sum of roots of polynomial which its constant term is $(1 -k^2)/4$.We can not get that with $-1$ and $3$ for $k=2$ and $k=20$.

Comment: @sirous Without dividing: the coefficient before $n^3$ it's $2\cdot2\cdot\frac{1}{2}=2,$ as we have.