# If $1+n+n^2+n^3$ is a perfect square, then $n=1$ or $n=7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that if $1+n+n^2+n^3$ is a perfect square then $n=1$ or $n=7$.

I managed to prove that $1+n+n^2+n^3=(n^2+1)(n+1)$ and that $(n^2+1,n+1)$ is either $1$ or $2$.
I found out that it could not be $1$, and then $\frac{1}{2}(n^2+1,n+1)=1$.

From here I concluded that $n^2+1=2a^2$ and $n+1=2b^2$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and it is here where I need some help.

Please only provide hints.

Comment: @Arthur In that case, both $n+1$ and $n^2 + 1$ would have to be perfect squares. $n^2+1$ can't be a perfect square since the only pair of squares that has a difference of $1$ is $0,1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Right, I _was_ missing something obvious. That being said, $n = 0$ looks valid to me, unless we are limited to strictly positive $n$.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116064/are-there-any-n-for-which-n4n3n2n1-is-a-perfect-square

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore yes, also the problem can be found here too :- https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h77372p444009

Comment: Some further observations: We know that $n^2 + 1$ can't be a perfect square. We have thus reduced our consideration to the case where $n^2 + 1 = 2^p a^2$ and $n + 1 = 2^qb^2$, where $a,b$ are odd. We know that because the product is a perfect square and $p$ can't be even, both $p$ and $q$ are odd. Because the gcd is at most $2$, we must either have $p=1$ or $q=1$.

In fact, it must be the case that $p = 1$. If $p > 1$, then we have $4 \mid (n^2 + 1)$, so that $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$, which means is impossible for $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: So, we can write $n^2 + 1 = 2a^2$, $n + 1 = 2^{2k+1} b^2$ where $a,b$ are odd and relatively prime.

Comment: Pell Equation at this point?

Comment: I thought thiis would be simple but it's a bit involved.  Can you tell us the motivation?

Comment: I started to study pythagorean triples and the equation $x^4+y^4=z^2$ by using Fermat's method of infinite descent. @fleablood

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $\gcd(n+1,n^2+1)=2$ then $n$ is odd, say $n=2k+1$, and so you get
$$a^2=\frac{n^2+1}{2}=\frac{4k^2+4k+2}{2}=k^2+(k+1)^2=k^2+b^4,$$
which is a Pythagorean triple. Can you continue from here? [There is still quite some work to be done!]

Answer (score 2):

Note that the LHS is a 4-term GP with $a = 1, r = n$. The sum is

$${1(1 - n^4) \over (1 - n)} = {n^4 - 1 \over n-1}$$

So, the equation becomes,

$${n^4 - 1 \over n-1} = y^2$$

This is the Nagell–Ljunggren Equation whose general form is:

$${x^n - 1 \over x - 1} = y^q$$

where, $x > 1, y > 1, n > 2, q ≥ 2$.

Known solutions are:

$${3^5 - 1 \over 3 - 1} = 11^2, {7^4 - 1 \over 7 - 1} = 20^2, {18^3 - 1 \over 18 - 1} = 7^3$$

So, for the 4th power version of your problem, $(7, 20)$ is the only known solution. I am not sure if there are other solutions possible. Need to study the original paper.

**References:**

See *2.2.4 The Nagell–Ljunggren Equation* in
**Perfect Powers:**
*Pillai’s works and their developments*
by M. Waldschmidt

[https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/PerfectPowers.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Emichel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/PerfectPowers.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old math olympiad problem.

The elementary solution involves repeated use of the [well-known parametrization of Pythagorean triples (Euclid's formula)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple).

You arrive at $n^2 + 1 = 2a^2$ and $n + 1 = 2b^2$, so that $2b^4 - 2b^2 + 1 = a^2$. Rewrite this as $(b^2)^2 + (b^2 - 1)^2 = a^2$ and use Euclid's formula.

Finally it gets down to Fermat's equations $x^4 \pm y^4 = z^2$, which have no non-trival solutions, as can be shown (again) by using Euclid's formula and infinite descent.

---

Nevertheless, a more advance approach is simply to view this as an elliptic curve and use a computer algebra system to find the integral points.

Run the following Sage code on [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to get the answer in no time:

```
EllipticCurve([0, 1, 0, 1, 1]).integral_points()
```

Output:

```
[(-1 : 0 : 1), (0 : 1 : 1), (1 : 2 : 1), (7 : 20 : 1)]
```

Comment: To make the answer complete, reference the descent proofs claimed in the elementary solution section.

Comment: @OscarLanzi The OP says "Please only provide hints", thus I don't give complete answer here. The output from Sage should not count, I think, as it doesn't contain any detail. I include it just to demonstrate the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

**I.** If $1+n+n^2+n^3=z^2$, and odd $n=2y+1$, then$$1+n+n^2+n^3=8y^3+16y^2+12y+4=z^2$$

Since $4$ divides $z^2$, then if $z^2=4w^2$ $$2y^3+4y^2+3y+1=w^2$$ and factoring $$(y+1)(2y^2+2y+1)=w^2$$

Now $y+1$ and $2y^2+2y+1$ are relatively prime, since if integer $k$ divides $y+1$, then $k$ divides $2y(y+1)=2y^2+2y$, and hence $k$ does not divide $2y^2+2y+1$.  If their product is square, then both $y+1$ and $2y^2+2y+1$ are squares.

**II.** Let $2y^2+2y+1$, which is odd, $=(2t+1)^2=4t^2+4t+1$.   Then$$y^2+y=2t^2+2t$$and$$\frac{y(y+1)}{2}=\frac{2t(t+1)}{2}$$Hence the LHS is a triangle number which is double a triangle number, and it lies in the sequence $$6,  210,  7140, 242556,   8239770,  279909630,  9508687656, ...$$and $y$ belongs in the sequence $$3, 20, 119, 696, 4059, 23660, 137903,...$$**III.** With a little more argument, drawing upon the sequence of solutions to the Pell equation$$b^2=2a^2 {^+_-} 1$$ it is possible to rule out all members of the $y$-sequence except $y=3$, and so prove that $n=7$.

I don't know if this approach is better than one by way of Pythagorean triples, but identifying $y$ as a factor in this relatively small sub-set of the triangle numbers seems a good way to go.